# Use of CIDR in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

I was studying about aws vpc and have come up with the following doubts:

1. What exactly is the use of mentioning the CIDR block for a subnet in a vpc?
   I created my vpc with CIDR as `10.0.0.0/16`. And then I created one subnet (public) with CIDR as `10.0.1.0/24`.
   When I launched an ec2 instance in this public subnet, the ec2 instance have been assigned a public IP (not in the defined CIDR block range of my subnet) and a private IP, which is within the defined CIDR range.
   So does the CIDR means that only these set of defined IPs will be able to access the vpc from outside? 
   And why is only the private IP defined within the CIDR range and not the public IP of the resource?
2. Also, how are we able to reserve a CIDR block for our vpc?
   I mean that there might be IP addresses that are already allocated on the internet, and suppose that some IPs out of `10.0.0.0/16` are already in use by devices across the world. 
   So, how am I able to choose that block of CIDR without any availability check?

Answer (score 4):

A CIDR range of `10.0.0.0/16` refers to all IP addresses that start with `10.0.x.x`.

A CIDR range of `10.0.1.0/8` is invalid because `/8` means that only the first number is fixed. For example, a CIDR range of `10.0.0.0/8` refers to all IP addresses starting with `10.x.x.x`. You probably wanted to assign a CIDR of `10.0.1.0/24`, which refers to all IP addresses starting with `10.0.1.x`.

CIDR addresses are always confusing. It's best to use a [CIDR calculator](https://cidr.xyz/) to interpret the IP address ranges.

IP addresses starting with `10.` are associated with [Private networks - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). They are used for *internal* routing and are not accessible on the Internet. A router (eg the router you have at home) translates between private address ranges and a Public IP address on the Internet.

You can create a VPC with private addresses and they will not overlap with other VPCs or corporate networks because `10.` networks are not part of the public Internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insightful answer. I have made the edits and corrected the CIDR range to `10.0.1.0/24`. Can we reserve the public ipv4 addresses by our choice? For example, can I assign 172.32. 0.0 - 191.0. 1.255, this range of public ipv4 addresses to my subnet (without any availability check)?

Comment: You should only assign Private IP address ranges to your VPC because Public IP address ranges are all assigned (the world is short of them!). You can obtain _individual_ public IP addresses by creating an [Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and then assigning it to your resources in the VPC (eg to an Amazon EC2 instance). The resource will retain both its Private IP address and its Public IP address.